# How to add a new line before #pragma mark using uncrustify?

Tags: objective-c, uncrustify

Is it possible to have uncrustify add some empty lines before/after the `#pragma mark -` directives?
If that is important, I am referring to Xcode 4.2 and iOS development in objC.

[EDIT] What I mean is something like the following:

```
// Some code here, and then 1 empty line

#pragma mark - Whatever

// Some other code here, after 1 empty line
```

becomes using uncrustify:

```
// Some code here, and then 2 empty lines


#pragma mark - Whatever


// Some other code here, after 2 empty lines
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.  Not because of a limitation in Uncrustify, but because of a limitation in XCode.

These two blocks behave identically in XCode:

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark
#pragma mark
#pragma mark -
```

and

```
// MARK: 
// MARK: 
// MARK: 
// MARK: 
// MARK: -
```

Try inserting a few of those lines above into any source code file.  You'll be able to see pretty quickly that XCode shows underlines for each of those blank `#pragma mark` lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if my initial question was clear enough, can you please double check after the edit?